# "has_many`のモデルに関するModuleを作りたい時の命名規則について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, 命名規則

例えば

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bars
end
```

とある時に `foo.bars` を使って計算する処理を Module でまとめておきたいのですが、
その時につけるModule名になんらかの命名規則はありますか？

できれば `Bars` や`BarsController`という名前をつけたいのですが、
そうすると既存の機能と被ってしまいますし良い案が浮かびません。

結局果たしている役割を使った命名を普段は行っているのですが、
もっと機械的に決定できる方法があれば知りたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

モデルの関心事を記述するモジュールのヘルパークラスとして、 `ActiveSupport::Concern` というものがありますので、 `Foo::BarsConcern` などにするのはいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

適切な抽象化した名前をつける事ができればそのほうがいいと思いますが、なかなかそうもいかないときは **`XxxRole`** とかつけることがあります。
この場合は **`BarsRole`** とかでしょうか。